# Swift map Algolia hit to Model

Tags: ios, json, swift, mvvm, algolia

I need to map the JSON object from Algolia to a Model.

Here's my ViewModel:

```
import Foundation
import AlgoliaSearchClient

class AlgoliaViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var idList: [MySearchModel] = []
    
    func search(text: String, index: String) {
        
        let client = SearchClient(appID: "XXX", apiKey: "XXX")
        let index = client.index(withName: IndexName(rawValue: index))
        let query = Query(text)
        
        index.search(query: query) { result in
            
            if case .success(let response) = result {
                print("Response: \(response)")
                
                do {
                    let hits: Array = response.hits
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.idList = hits.map({
                            MySearchModel(searchValue: $0.objectID.rawValue)
                            })
                        print(self.idList)
                    }
                }
                catch {
                    print("JSONSerialization error:", error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For the moment, I just have a Model with the objectID as searchValue.

How can I access to all other attributes of my Object and map them to a Model?

Answer (score 1):

```
import Foundation
import AlgoliaSearchClient

class AlgoliaViewModel: ObservableObject {

@Published var list: [MySearchModel] = []

func search(text: String, index: String) {
    
    let client = SearchClient(appID: "XXX", apiKey: "XXX")
    let index = client.index(withName: IndexName(rawValue: index))
    let query = Query(text)
    
    index.search(query: query) { result in
        
        if case .success(let response) = result {
            print("Response: \(response)")
            
            do {
                let hits: Array = response.hits
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.list = hits.map({MySearchModel.init})
                    print(self.list)
                }
            }
            catch {
                print("JSONSerialization error:", error)
            }
        }
     }
  }
}
```